# How to send/recive http data on Qt?

Tags: qt, curl

I'm trying to do some thing like a simple curl function that can do like sending a Get/Post request and set the response text in a label.

I have read about QNAM, but that's complicated.

Is there any simple way to do that(*without all the signal and slot*) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you'll want to read up on [the QHttp class](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qhttp.html)

It doesn't require too much work with signals and slots, however if you don't want to use them you may want to consider an alternative to Qt as it relies on them quite heavily.

Comment: QHttp is deprecated. Its functionality was replaced by [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) and the surrounding classes.

Comment: @grefab The link in your comment is outdated and the new one is [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html). Qt should set up some redirects on its website.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it could be useful [QtCUrl](https://github.com/pavlonion/qtcurl) binding. It is very simple for those who is familiar with curl.